# Limit on the amount of queues and verticles in Vert.x

Tags: java, actor, vert.x

We are now in the process of refactoring our messaging application written in Vert.x. The application processes incoming messages from users. Initially, it was implemented so that there is a single verticle instance that listens to a single queue in the event bus and processes all the incoming messages.

What we are thinking of doing is to refactor it so that it works a bit similar to actor model: we deploy an instance of a verticle for each active user and make it listen to a user-specific queue. This way the verticle instance can maintain user-specific state and the parallelization of the message processing becomes much easier.

The issue, however, is that this would lead to a huge number of verticles deployed (30k - 50k in parallel) and huge amount of queues in the eventbus. And also we would need to maintain the verticles manually (undeploy unused verticles and deploy the ones when there is a message from a new user).

Question is - is this actor-style architecture good for vert.x and can it handle large amount of deployed verticles and eventbus queues at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one major correction to be made here - EventBus is a single queue. So, you won't have "huge number of queues". There will be only one. You'll have huge number of addresses on a single queue.

But is this number so huge? Well, is a HashMap of 50K elements can be considered huge? Probably not, at least in terms of keys. Now note that this applies only to Vert.x in non-clustered mode. Clustered Vert.x is different (still should work, though).

Now having those verticles is another matter. Each verticle is a separate object, and if you plan to store some data in it, it will be even larger. But if you can afford machines with some decent RAM (16GB+), it should work just fine.

What does concern me in this solution, though, is that you plan to deploy verticles on demand, then undeploy them. It does incur delays, so your users will experience degraded performance for first message they send.

Answer (score 1):

What you call "actor-style" does not mean, that you have to inflate a new verticle instance per user. If you do so, you are going to get a system with 98% redundancy.

It's absolutely enough to register an event-bus address for each user and use some sort of persistant storage to keep track of them. Such a storage can be any DB for long-term persistance or a cluster-wide `SharedMap` for short-term, or a combination of both.

Perhaps you don't even need a address-per-user scheme. Such a scheme is nice when the users are connected constantly to your system via some sort of `EventBusBridge`. If this is not a case, you can register a single event-bus address for all users and process messages based on payload.